# Where is the shutdown log?

Tags: shutdown, log

I am trying to debug a hang during shutdown and I don't find where the messages that I see during shutdown are being stored.  They aren't in `/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 14):

Your cellphone video camera. Seriously. It's not physically possible for linux to record a log after the "Unmounting local filesystems" message. And for some reason, Ubuntu Oneiric never records *any* of the shutdown messages, even errors warnings and "[fail]s", at least not anywhere I can find them using `sudo grep`.

If you have the plymouth splash screen on shutdown that hides the console messages with the Ubuntu logo and progress dots, then hit `ESC` to see what's going on behind the curtains... and record it with your video camera for playback later.

Answer (score 10):

Try looking in `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/*.log`

Or,

```
sudo find /var/log -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo zgrep "the message you are interested in"
```

Comment: As of Ubuntu 16.04 this sadly seems no longer correct. None of the recently written-to suspects (`root@x230:/var/log> ll -tr | tail') has any of the messages I tried to grep (and manually checked for, too!).