# How to read shutdown/reboot log

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, shutdown, reboot

I own a laptop running 12.10 with Gnome 3.6 (installed on a SSD). I have been noticing since 12.04 that when rebooting, the computer hangs for about 30 seconds (sometimes even more) with a black screen and the laptop fan at maximum speed, before booting up again. On the other hand, the shutdown process is considerably faster.

Is there way to check the shutdown log, to help identify a problem?

Comment: try bootchart [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/198685/ubuntu-12-04-takes-too-long-to-boot-what-should-i-do)

Comment: isn't bootchart just supposed to save the boot log? My problem is during the shutdown, when I issue a reboot. A simple shutdown takes just a few seconds (normal).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58625/where-is-the-shutdown-log BUT a computer hanging for 30 seconds does not imply a log is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing "quiet splash" from GRUB configuration file, I was able to observe the output of the shutdown/reboot process. Seems that the OS is hanging form about 1m30s in "Restarting System", something that only happens when issuing a reboot (NOT on shutdown).

Comment: pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> will achieve the same (it being visible. Sadly I don't know yet, if it's written anywhere. /var/log/* seems not to be it...)