# 14.04 and needs "sudo reboot" twice to reboot

Tags: 14.04, reboot

I insalled my 14.04 freshly and added a lot of packages to fulfill my purpose.

From a certain stage on, I have to type in "sudo reboot" twice to really get my system to reboot.

After the 1st "sudo reboot" I do get the system warning about going down, but not more.....

Comment: Does the command `sudo shutdown -r now` do it immediately?

Comment: Nope.... Even "sudo shutdown -r now" brings the warning, there is no reboot. Even I now do the "sudo shutdown -r now" twice, it just brings the warning twice (or more times) but not even reboots! Just a final "sudo reboot" (after the "sudo shutdown -r now") works......

Comment: What about `sudo shutdown -r 1` Does that do it in 1 min?

Comment: It brings the warning "The system is going down for reboot in 1 minute!"..... after ~1min, it brings the warning again saying "NOW" but again just stays at the prompt....

Comment: very strange...

Comment: surprisingly some of my processes seam to be terminated (such as smb) by the 1st "reboot".....

Comment: This is confusing... Does shutting down from the menu work?

Comment: In deed. I am kind of out of ideas.

Comment: I did a reboot from the menu.... here it hangs in the going down process at the "UBUNTU" logo and keeps on filling the 5 progress dots..... HDD LED blinks from time to time.   Is there a "shutown"-log?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58625/where-is-the-shutdown-log

Comment: I am also having issues with the coming up of the system.... keeps on hanging at the grub menu screen: http://askubuntu.com/questions/506891/14-04-and-grub-hanging-after-reboot