# How to detect if it was an unexpected power down

Tags: shutdown, logs

I'm trying to find/figure out if a computer using Ubuntu 16 had an unexpected power down.

I checked many sources on Internet, review the logs in the /var/log files, but I could not find any clear indication about this kind of events.

I'm running Ubuntu VMs under either Windows Hyper-V and Virtualbox. As a matter of testing, I can power off the VM and I expect to be able to find this event in the logs, similar that I can do with the Windows Logs.

I know that I can write my own way writing a file in a script at the shutdown time and looking for this file at the boot time, but considering the maturity of Linux/Ubuntu, I think should be something already, and trying to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/q/58625/295286  Proper shutdown means unmounting of  the `/` filesystem (usually `/dev/sda1` ) , so if you don't find that line, it probably wasn't a proper shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the file `/var/log/kern.log*`, and find the most recent

```
Jun 28 10:16:08 aardvark kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu 
#   Time/date   hostname  who    usec since boot
```

That's the first thing that gets logged when the system comes up. The lines of `/var/log/kern.log*` just before that line are the last events logged before the system went down. If there are no errors or warnings above the `[   0.000000]` line, or if there is a large interval of time between last pre-crash event and the first boot line, suspect power. It takes some form of UPS or battery backup to be able to log "Power is off".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nice sudo zgrep "recovery complete" /var/log/kern.log*
```

Output example for Proxmox 5 (Debian 9 stretch, Linux 4.15.18):

```
/var/log/kern.log:Apr 21 18:56:16 pve kernel: [   83.475918] EXT4-fs (dm-8): recovery complete
/var/log/kern.log.1:Apr 18 18:01:39 pve kernel: [   89.627622] EXT4-fs (dm-8): recovery complete
/var/log/kern.log.3.gz:Apr  5 19:00:09 pve kernel: [   83.572224] EXT4-fs (dm-8): recovery complete
```

Yes, here is bad situation, because of often unexpected shutdowns, so I have to replace battery in my UPS.