# Ubuntu 16 - shutdown logs

Tags: encryption, shutdown, 16.10, log

Is there any file in Ubuntu 16 that records the shutdown logs? I'm stuck with some kind of error in my laptop, my disk is encrypted and Ubuntu is not able to either reboot or shutdown properly, so I'd like to check what's going on.

```
$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: resilva-Inspiron-5548
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 3cd0030af8a7459c985a7c2662f865f3
           Boot ID: f2e930d1b0b645cd9942f7d0416f86aa
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.10
            Kernel: Linux 4.8.0-32-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Thanks!

Comment: Investigate the output of `journalctl`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the shutdown log?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58625/where-is-the-shutdown-log)